# ReactJs How to access child components refs from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to access the refs of children in a parent to do something with them in the parent function?

```
class Parent extends Component {

  someFunction(){
  // how to access h1 element of child in here ??
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child />
    );
  }
}



class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1 ref="hello">Hello</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the second line of the question is actually first line of the code . cant format that because of this stupid checks this website has in place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to Shubham's answer, the child refs have to be accessed inside of componentDidMount() inside parent. Something like:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        var elem1 = this.refs.child1.refs.childRefName;
    }

    return (
    <View>
      <Child1 ref='child1'/>
      <Child2 />
      <Child3 />
    </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Its not necessary to be accessed in componentDidMount, it can be accessed in any function, if we have proper binding. And we should ideally be using ReactDOM.findDOMNode() too along with refs. You answer doesn't add anything over my answer

Comment: Can you give an example of proper binding?
And why do you think use of ReactDOM.findDOMNode() is ideal; what might happen if we don't use it?

Comment: This will not work on connected component( a component that is connected to redux or other plugins ). we need to use getWrappedInstance() to get the wrapped instance and then we can access the state, refs and methods of that component. Here is the video explaining it - https://youtu.be/VpdKjocgCtA

Answer (score 3):

You can access the child refs by providing a ref to the child element and accessing it like `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.child.refs.hello)`

In your case the child component doesn't begin with Uppercase letter which you need to change.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
       console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.child.refs.hello));
   
   }
   render() {
      return (
        <Child ref="child"/>
      );
     }
    }
class Child extends React.Component {
     render() {
      return (
        <h1 ref="hello">Hello</h1>
      );
     }
    }
    
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<divi id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `React.forwardingRef` method to make the `Child` component able to receive and define a `ref` from its parent.

Here is the documentation for the method:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

And here is an example of how you might implement it in your code:

```
const Child = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => (
  <h1 ref={ref}>Child Component</h1>
));

function Parent() {
  var h1 = React.createRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(h1.current);
  });

  return <Child ref={h1} />;
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

I hope it helps.